# how to run sox command from java code in windows environment using cmd

Tags: java, cmd, sox

Below is the code i wrote to trim wav file using the sox. sox is installed in my system if i use the sox command directly in cmd it works fine but in java code its run partially and there is no outfile created. now i m receiving 'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

```
Process p=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start cmd.exe /K \"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\sox-14-4-2\\sox.exe && sox D:\\Office\\VoiceClipping\\AudioFiles\\test.wav  D:\\Office\\VoiceClipping\\AudioFiles\\ans.wav trim 5 =10\"");
        p.waitFor();
        BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream())
        );
        String line;
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If a directory has spaces in, put quotes around it.In your case, put quotates around `"Program Files (x86)"`.

Comment: thanks for the reply, i change my installation directory for sox now i m using   " Process p=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start cmd.exe /K \"sox D:\\Office\\VoiceClipping\\AudioFiles\\test.wav  D:\\Office\\VoiceClipping\\AudioFiles\\ans.wav trim 5 =10\"");" but still sox command is not passing to cmd.